# wordpress shortcode attributes not being passed

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've created a short code that I'm trying to pass an attribute into, but I don't seem to be receiving the value on the other end.

Here's what I've got below;

```
    function list_display($atts) {
       extract( shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'pageName' => 'No Page Received',
            ), $atts )
        );

    echo $pageName;

    add_shortcode('list-briefings-display', 'list_display');
    }
```

and the shortcode being used is

```
     [list-display pageName="My Page Name"]
```

and I'm running a require_once from functions.php

```
    require_once ( TEMPLATEPATH. '/includes/list-display.php' );
```

But what I'm seeing on the screen is 'No Page Received', can anyone think of something I might've missed?

There is more content being generated by the shortcode, which I have't included, that's rendering fine. So it just seems to be something to do with how I've passed the attribute.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function list_display($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'pagename' => 'No Page Received'
     ), $atts );
     extract($atts);

     echo $pagename;
}

add_shortcode('list-display', 'list_display');
```

You'll probably want to use "return" instead of "echo" if you're using the shortcode within pages and posts.. Echo could cause it to send output to the screen a little too early and won't end up exactly where you may be expecting it to be.

There was also a little formatting issue in your code that I've corrected, mainly trying to use add_shortcode() from within the very same function you're trying to reference. I also changed the first parameter of add_shortcode() to the shortcode you were trying to use in your example.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, switching to return solved the issue.